# Is it possible to access another keyword in called function parameter?

Tags: python, oop

I'm not sure how to completely articulate what I'm wondering here so forgive any confusion.

What I want to know is, Once I import a module and call a function is it possible to access another parameter's value inside another parameter within the same function?

So for example, I'm playing around with `pandas` at the moment and I've created a series with a basic block of code:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [40, 70, 90]
series = pd.Series(data=data, name='marks', index=[i for i in range(0, len(data))])
```

But I want to see if it's possible to do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

series = pd.Series(data=[40, 70, 90], name='marks', index=[i for i in range(0, len(__get_value_from_data_keyword__))])
```

where `__get_value_from_data_keyword__` returns the value of the `data` keyword in the same function. So `__get_value_from_data_keyword__` equals `[40, 70, 90]`

Is this possible to do at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an assignment expression to get a reference to the "anonymous" value.

```
series = pd.Series(data=(x := [40, 80, 90]), name='marks', index=list(range(0, len(x))))
```

However, this would be much more readable as

```
x = [40, 80, 90]
series = pd.Series(data=x, name='marks', index=list(range(x)))
```

Comment: Ah ok thanks. Although I was thinking that some dunder method would of been the answer, since it's not possible, I'll accept this as the answer since it's close enough to a one liner that was also something I was thinking would be preferable

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your question - no.
In Python, you cannot directly access the value of a parameter inside another parameter within the same function.